# Editable textview on click

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I have a screen with textviews now i want to make this editable on click of that

i tried one solution using edittext making it as transparent background but initially it will show cursor and the click is not recognizing properly,if i set focusbaleintouchmode to false in xml it is not getting focus.but some how the click is not working properly as expected.first is this correct approach?

expected result is textview should be there once user clicks on it it should be editable once user clicks outside it it should be not editable. any sample code will helps me a lot.sorry for my english

Thanks in advance

finally i got one solution using below code
in xml edit text i gave foucasbletouchmode to false which makes click works properly after that with in onclick

```
        et.setFocusable(true);
        et.setEnabled(true);

        et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        et.requestFocus();
```

to lose focus

```
        et.setFocusable(false);
        et.setClickable(true);
        et.clearFocus();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the below code :

```
private makeEditable(boolean isEditable,EditText et){
    if(isEditable){
        et.setBackgroundDrawable("Give the textbox background here");//You can store it in some variable and use it over here while making non editable.
        et.setFocusable(true);
        et.setEnabled(true);
        et.setClickable(true);
        et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        et.setKeyListener("Set edit text key listener here"); //You can store it in some variable and use it over here while making non editable.
    }else{
        et.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
        et.setFocusable(false);
        et.setClickable(false);
        et.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        et.setEnabled(false);
        et.setKeyListener(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but some how my linearlayout is not recognizing click event    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/goallinearlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  i want to ur code in that onclick
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

Comment: no first of all my linear layout is not getting cliked properly in that three child elements were there (textview,edittext,view) i added on clicklistener to linear layout with in that i have to place your code

Comment: I guess the edittext is inside your linear layout. The click events are bubbled to the parents. so if you make the clickable true on edit texts, it will capture the click event and bubble it to its parent ie. linear layout. try that..

Comment: the actual problem is setFoucusableintouchMode i read that for the edittext first click will focus the edittext and second click will actually fires click event.according to the code submitted we are forcing setfocusabletouchmode to true means for every second click it will capture the event and it will not work as expected :(

Comment: can you tell me how to forcefully remove the focus for edittext i mean to make not editable without using setfocusable or setfocusabletouchmode because it is affecting click event

Comment: finally i found a solution your code helps me thanks check for edit for solution thanks